# How to use sanity data directly in javascript

Tags: javascript, nuxtjs3, sanity

I'm using Sanity as CMS for my Nuxt 3 website and I can't manage to access the data object in javascript after fetching the data.

There is the error code:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  const query = groq`*[_type == "seoContent"]{
              seoTitle,
              seoDescription,
            }[0]`
  const { data, refresh } = useSanityQuery(query)

  console.log(data.seoTitle)

  // if(data.seoTitle) {
  //   useServerSeoMeta({
  //     title: data.seoTitle,
  //     ogTitle: data.seoTitle,
  //     description: data.seoDescription,
  //     ogDescription: data.seoDescription,
  //   })
  // }
  
</script>
```

That's the scheme:

```
export default {
    name: 'seoContent',
    type: 'document',
    title: 'SEO Content',
    fields: [
        { name: 'title', type: 'string', title: 'Document Title' },
        { name: 'seoTitle', type: 'string', title: 'SEO Title' },
        { name: 'seoDescription', type: 'string', title: 'SEO Description' },
    ]
}
```

Otherwise I have always passed the data as props to the respective component and that has always worked. Also, a simple console.log(data) returns the data I expect, but when I try to console.log(data.seoTitle) I get an undefined... Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Answer (score 0):

When using useSanityQuery it returns a reactive proxy which must be access with .value. This is the case for most composables.

In your case this would be: `data.value.seoTitle` , this only applies in setup.